# Error while using interface as a type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I'm querying a table with a SQL query (table is decided dynamically). All the tables implement the ITableIsFile interface. Here is the problematic code.

```
            string sql = "Select * from " + file + " where userID = '" + currAgentTM.systemuserid.Value
            + "' and CallStatusID = null";
        var records = appelsDataContext.ExecuteQuery<ITableIsFile>(sql);
```

On the last line, I get the following error: The type 'MRS_Admin.ITableIsFile' must declare a default (parameterless) constructer in order to be constructed during mapping.

From what I know (and have tested), it is not possible to implement a constructor in an interface.

Thank you for any help you can provide, it is much appreciated.
Mathieu

Comment: I think you may need to supply a concrete class that implements your interface, not your interface directly.

Comment: But I don't know which table will be queried. Or maybe I'm not using the best way to query?

Comment: If your set on using string sql statements I'd drop the linq context and map the returned raw dataset to my  objects directly, probably with reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think AS-CII means that you should create a base class from the interface, and use that type.  For example, instead of:

```
interface ISomething { }

class SomethingOne : ISomething { }

class SomethingTwo : ISomething { }
```

try:

```
interface ISomething { }

class SomethingBase : ISomething { }

class SomethingOne : SomethingBase { }

class SomethingTwo : SomethingBase { }
```

But note the requirements in the remarks section here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean. Sorry, I did not read carefully. I'm retesting and it seems to work. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

TResult must be a concrete class that the data context is cabable of mapping the return set to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the implementation of the interface with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: If I add a constructor to the interface, I get: Interfaces cannot contain constructors

Comment: In fact you don't have to put the constructor in your interface. You must implement the interface in a concrete class.